# how can I create a list of background images' URLs and apply them on click function with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the background image of the HTML body to be extracted from the list of images URLs and randomly or sequentially (sequentially preferred) a new image to be applied for each time a button on the page is clicked.

so it has to be something like this:

```
var images = ["URL1", "URL2", "URL3"];

$("button").onclick(function(){
//choose a random/sequential image from var images and use it as a background image for my body

// on another click choose a different background-image from images and use it as background

// and so on
});
```

Comment: what is the problem? what is the question?

Comment: I will edit, 1 moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you can do it randomly & next & prev like that:

```
var imagesArr = ["1.jpg","2.jpg"];
var selectedImage = 0;

$("button").click(function(){
  var item = imagesArr[Math.floor(Math.random()* imagesArr.length)];
  document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundImage = item;
});

$(".nextButton").click(function(){
   if(selectedImage < imagesArr.length){
      selectedImage++;
      document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundImage = imagesArr[selectedImage];
   }
});

$(".prevButton").click(function(){
   if(selectedImage > 1){
      selectedImage--;
      document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundImage = imagesArr[selectedImage];
   }
});
```

Comment: I just don't understand why you have 3 buttons with different functions? it is supposed to one button to be clicked

Comment: 1 button for all actions?

Comment: yes, 1 button to generate a random background image each time it's clicked

Comment: then it is just the first function with button instance, you can remove the others